# ADODB Connection - Webserver doesn't resolve the hostname of the mssql server

Tags: database, ms-sql

I have a mssql connection resource file as belows:

`<% Set Conn01 = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection") Conn01.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=forum;UID=forumuser;PWD=forumpass;APP=;Initial Catalog=forumdb" %>`

The webserver can interact with the database server when an user logs into the forum BUT I can't ping "forum" machine from the webserver machine. It says "host doesn't resolve." So how am I supposed to know the IP of the database server? There is only a name called "forum" but it doesn't resolve to anything when I attempted pinging the machine.

I need to know the IP address of this data source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`forum` is the name of your host's *local database server* (i.e. the MSSQL server). Your scripts are hosted locally in relation to the database, which is why you can use them to reference `forum`.  However, your own computer is on an outside network in which `forum` has no meaning.  If that's not clear, imagine if lots of people all named their MSSQL servers, `forum`.  How would anyone be able to resolve the correct `forum` server they wanted?

If you do need the IP address then you should talk to your host's technical support.

Comment: Well, so, how does the webserver reach the database? We have like 10 machines in the local area network but we don't have any machine named "forum".

Comment: The reason your database works for users browsing the forum is because the forum (ASP/ASP.NET) scripts are uploaded to the webserver too, making the database server visible to them.  If the webserver is in-house and you're wanting access to the database server via your LAN, then you need to look into [Enabling Network Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718.aspx).